# Regarding filters in django

Tags: javascript, html, django, filter

```
 <div class="project-container">
      <div class="project-header">
        <div class="status-container">
          <h1 class="project-header-text">{{ project_instance.projectTitle }}</h1>
          <select id="select1"  name ="status" onchange="getOption()">
            <option value="#">Search for status</option>
            <option value="Show all" selected>Show all</option>
            <option value="I">In progress</option>
            <option value="C">Completed</option>
            <option value="R">Submitted for Review</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="progress-create-btn">
            <a href="./project_details.html"><button class="project-header-btn btns">View Project Details</button></a>
            <a href="./progress.html"><button class="project-header-btn btns">View Progress</button></a>
            <a href="{% url 'create-task' project_id=project_instance.projectID %}"><button class="project-header-btn btns">Create Task</button></a>
            <!-- <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for Status.." title="Type in a name"> -->
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="project-body">
        <table class="main-table" id="maintable">
          <thead>
            <th>Tasks</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>View task</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {% for task in task_instance %}
            <tr class="table-row">
                <td class="table-data">{{ task.taskTitle }}</td>
                <td class="table-data">
                    <h3 class="label-tag">
                        {% if task.status == 'I' %}
                            Pending
                        {% elif task.status == 'C' %}
                            Completed
                        {% elif task.status == 'R' %}
                            Submitted for Review
                        {% else %}
                            Unknown
                        {% endif %}
                    </h3>
                </td>
                <td class="table-data">
                    <a href="{% url 'view-tasks' project_id=project_instance.projectID %}">
                        <button class="button-tag btns">View</button>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% empty %}
            <tr class="table-row">
                <td class="table-data" colspan="4">No tasks to show</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}

          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
```

This is my html code

```
function myFunction(filter) {
  var table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  // input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  // filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  filter=filter.toUpperCase();
  if(filter=="SHOW ALL"){
    filter="";
  }
  table = document.querySelector(".main-table");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
function getOption() {
  selectElement = document.querySelector('#select1');
  output = selectElement.value;
  myFunction(output);
}
```

This is my js

```
def view_task(request,project_id):
    
    project_instance = project.objects.get(projectID=project_id) 
    task_instance=Task.objects.filter(projectID=project_instance)
    
    context = {'project_instance': project_instance,'task_instance':task_instance}
    return render(request, 'manager/manager_view_project.html', context)
```

This is my django view

Now when I change filter options it should show task changes accordingly dynamically without refreshing the page what should I do  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4ZxD.png)

I tried to change but I am not able to execute it

Now I have tried changing it please give some solution

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take a moment to use a tour of the [meta]. To ask good questions, see [ask].

Comment: Django lives in the server, while the JavaScript lives in the client computer.  Django replaces the tags with the variables *from the server*, and sends the resulting html to the client.  Once there, the client, that is, the browser, does not understand these tags, and anyway the variables for those tags aren't there anymore.  So for example, in `{% if task.status == 'I' %}`, when you change the filter, `task.status` will not change.  The easiest solution is to *change the text of the status in your JavaScript once you detect the change*.  You already know how to detect the change.